# Is there a way to show a word document and change the color of its lines in ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using `Ionic 4`. I load a word document using [`FileOpener`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-opener). 
This gives me only a preview though.

I would like to be able to change the colour of each line using a pattern, e.g: red-green-red-green-... and red-green-blue-red-green-blue-... on pressing a button in the toolbar.

Is there a way to achieve that? I was wondering if you could give me any ideas and help me achieve the desired functionality, please?

Thank you in advance

Comment: This is not possible using Ionic (or any web framework). In order to manipulate an opened Word document you would need to access the Word instance via an ActiveX interface which is legacy technology and has long been disabled in browsers due to security issues.

Comment: Ok,good to know. Thank you very much for your information.

Comment: I was wondering though . Could i a) first create a copy of the file, b) change the color of each line ,using FileWriter : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova/file/filewriter/filewriter.html and then c) show the file using FileOpener ? What do you think? Is it possible?

Comment: If you're dealing with `.docx` files you might be able to parse the XML format and add the required markup to change text color. Yet it wouldn't help you as you can't predict which text is going to appear on which line.

Comment: What about Officegen:https://www.npmjs.com/package/officegen

Comment: I am working with docx. How can i access the xml format of the document,please?